# A sufficient condition on square matrix $A$ such that $AP$ is positive-definite, where $P$ is a square positive diagonal matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices, positive-definite

I am trying to find a sufficient condition on square matrix $A$ to guarantee that $AP$ is positive-definite, where $P$ is a square positive diagonal matrix. The positive-definite here means the symmetric part of $AP$, $\frac{AP+PA^T}{2}$, is positive-definite.

I think this problem is related to the Lyapunov's equation $-AP-PA^T+Q = 0$. Say to find a sufficient condition on $A$ so that there exists a symmetric positive-definite $Q$ such that $P$ is a solution of the Lyapunov's equation $-AP-PA^T+Q = 0$.

Is it correct? How can I proceed?

---

In fact, I already know that $$A = \left(\begin{array}{cc} \delta+(1-\frac{1}{n})k_{1} &-\frac{1}{n} k_{2} &... &-\frac{1}{n} k_{n} \\
-\frac{1}{n} k_{1} &\delta+(1-\frac{1}{n})k_{2} &... &-\frac{1}{n} k_{n} \\
...&...&...&... \\
-\frac{1}{n} k_{1} &-\frac{1}{n} k_{2} &... &\delta+(1-\frac{1}{n})k_{n}\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{cc} \delta+k_{1} &0 &... &0 \\
0 &\delta+k_{2} &... &0 \\
...&...&...&... \\
0 &0 &... &\delta+k_{n}\end{array}\right)
- \frac{1}{n}\left(\begin{array}{cc} k_{1} &k_{2} &... &k_{n} \\
k_{1} &k_{2} &... &k_{n} \\
...&...&...&... \\
k_{1} &k_{2} &... &k_{n}\end{array}\right).$$
I think this is very closed to the sufficient condition since if we let $k_{1} = ... = k_{n} = 1$ and $P = I$, then
$$\frac{AP+PA^T}{2} = AP = \left(\begin{array}{cc} \delta+(1-\frac{1}{n}) &-\frac{1}{n} &... &-\frac{1}{n} \\
-\frac{1}{n} &\delta+(1-\frac{1}{n}) &... &-\frac{1}{n} \\
...&...&...&... \\
-\frac{1}{n} &-\frac{1}{n} &... &\delta+(1-\frac{1}{n})\end{array}\right) = (1+\delta)I - \frac
{1}{n}1 1^T,$$ and the eigenvalue can be calculated by $|\lambda I - AP| = |(\lambda -1-\delta)I + \frac
{1}{n}1 1^T| = (\lambda -1-\delta)^{n-1}(\lambda-\delta)$, all the eigenvalues are positive.